# C++ Struct Size unequal C++ Struct Size in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++, struct, c++-cli

my question refers to the problem mentioned in the title.

I have a simple struct in a header file that looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    WORD FileType;          // File ID (0x7000)
    WORD HeaderSize;        // Size of this file header in Bytes
    WORD HeaderVersion;     // yy.y
    ULONG FileSize;         // Size of the whole file in Bytes
    WORD ImageHeaderSize;   // Size of the image header in Bytes
    WORD ULX, ULY, BRX, BRY;// bounding rectangle of the image
    WORD NrOfFrames;        // self explanatory
    WORD Correction;        // 0 = none, 1 = offset, 2 = gain, 4 = bad pixel, (ored)
    double IntegrationTime; // frame time in microseconds
    WORD TypeOfNumbers;     // short, long integer, float, signed/unsigned, inverted, 
                            // fault map, offset/gain correction data, badpixel correction data
    BYTE x[WINRESTSIZE];        // fill up to 68 byte
} WinHeaderType;
```

If I call sizeof(WinHeaderType) in a C console application I get 68,
but if I call the same function with the same parameter in C++/CLI I get 80.

Could someone explain this behaviour to me?

I'm pretty new to C++/CLI, in fact I never worked with it before
(started a few days ago), but I need to create a dll for .NET applications.

Since it's my first post I hope I did not break any of the forum rules.

Greez,
Mo

[EDIT] It just becomes stranger and stranger ...

[image]

First Row: C Console Application Output

Second Row, First Column: C/C++ Console Application I coded to check DataType sizes.

Second Row, Second Column: C++/CLI Console Application I coded to check DataType sizes.

Source of the first application: http://fbe.am/sId

Project Files of the last two applications: http://fbe.am/sIf

Someone an explanaition for this?!

Comment: Maybe your console application don't have padding of the fields? Maybe `WINRESTSIZE` is different? Maybe `WORD` is different? And most importantly of all, C++/CLI is *not* C++.

Comment: Please show complete programs. We cannot tell for sure what the macros are. Complete C program, and complete C++/CLI program.

Comment: The C console application uses the same header as the C++/CLI DLL.
I know that C++/CLI is not C++, but CLI has native data types integrated since it uses C++(?) or ported C++(?) headers anyway.
I didn't check the padding thing, but shouldn't do I have the same result using C++/CLI? I call C function and native (unmanaged) datatypes in C++/CLI aswell and furthermore how would the compiler optimize the size of the struct members when they are from numeric nature with a fixed size ... ? Maybe I'm talking trash, I would appreciate if you guys would correct me if I'm wrong :D

Comment: @David Heffernan: http://fbe.am/sIc (CLI - not compilable, make sure you keep in mind that "Acq.h" from Console.rar is needed)
http://fbe.am/sId (C++ Console Application - compilable)
Please don't think I'm a bad programmer 'cause of the CLI code,
I know it looks horrible, but I'm pretty desperated and so
I tried pretty everything on earth (casting like a mage) to bring it to run properly.

Comment: Please can we have the two programs in the question. You need to make SSCCEs. All we need is the shortest possible program. It declares the type, and prints the size.

Comment: I posted the first program, but I can't post the full source code of the second one, because I'm legally not allowed to post it.
In both applications the datatypes are defined in minwindef.h.
So they are exactly of the same size ... !
There is also a cheat sheet for datatypes [link]http://wuxuesong.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/c-cli-cheat-sheet.pdf
I also checked the sizes programmatically ... all the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With default packing rules (/Zp8), the structure contains 12 bytes of padding to get the members aligned.  Which ought to be good enough to explain the difference between 68 and 80.  You'll have to eliminate the padding, use `#pragma pack` in the MSVC compiler:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct {
   // .. etc
} WinHeaderType;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: Beautiful <3 Thanks, that's it. But why isn't there a keyword for that like Pascal has with its "packed record"? It seems very laborious to me that I have to carry for that option with pragma comments.

Comment: The C and C++ languages don't invest heavily in keywords that make code slower.  Alignment is a pretty big deal, reading a mis-aligned *double* can be three times slower on a friendly processor, hundreds of times slower on an unfriendly one.

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably related to the definition of WORD being different in both cases.
BYTE, WORD and ULONG are not native C++ type, so check where/how there are defined.

BYTE is probably a single char.
ULONG probably an unsigned long.
But WORD is probably different in your case.

Comment: I edited my question where I added an image, source code and projects files. If you look at the image, you will see that the datatypes don't differ from each other in other C languages.