# C++/CLI representation has different values than Native C++ Structure

Tags: c++, struct, c++-cli, wrapper

I have a Problem using a native C++ structure in my C++/CLI Wrapper. As I understand it, to wrap a structure in a C++/CLI wrapper I create a new wrapper structure and copy the values e.g. in the constructor.

Hence, I have a problem with the native structure. If i break the application in a method of my wrapped native class I get the correct results (see figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akvk6.png)). But if I break my application in my CLI Project I get the result shown in figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuG57.png).

I both times reference the same structure. I do not get, why C++/CLI mixes up the values. Can it be the fault of the array? on my native side it has fixed 240 characters, in C++/CLI it does not.

A hint would be much appreciated. If you need more Information please let me know.

Content in managed code:
[image: Content in managed code]
[image: Content in native code]

EDIT:

Code of my wrapping struct as Example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a PNIO Device.
/// </summary>
public ref struct PnioDevice
{
public:
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new PNIO Device Struct for CLR use.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = devPtr> The pointer to the T_PNIO_DEVICE_PROP Struct (C++/CLI use only).
    PnioDevice(T_PNIO_DEVICE_PROP dev)
    {
        ipAddress = gcnew IpAddress(dev.tIpParam);
        macAddress = InterfaceProperties::MacAddressFromByteArray(dev.tMacProp.abMacAddr);
        stationName = gcnew String(dev.tNameOfStation);
    }
    /// <summary> Mac Address of the device </summary>
    /// <value> Mac-Address separated with ':' </value>
    property String ^ MacAddress
    {
        String ^ get()
        {
            return macAddress;
        }
    }

    /// <summary> Ip Address of the device </summary>
    /// <value> Ip Address Structure </value>
    property IpAddress ^ IPAddress
    {
        IpAddress ^ get()
        {
            return ipAddress;
        }
    }
    /// <summary> Station Name of the Device </summary>
    /// <value> The name of the Station as String </value>
    property String ^ StationName
    {
        String ^ get()
        {
            return stationName;
        }
    }
private:
    String ^ macAddress;
    IpAddress ^ ipAddress;
    String ^ stationName;
};
```

And the Type Definition of the structure I would like to wrap. This structure is stored in my native C++ class I'd like to wrap.

```
/** Device properties */
typedef struct PNIO_ATTR_PACKED
{
  /** MAC propertie */
  T_PNIO_MC_PROP      tMacProp;
  /** IP propertie */
  T_PNIO_IP_PROP      tIpParam;
  /** Name of station */
  T_PNIO_NAME_OF_STATION_PROP tNameOfStation;

}T_PNIO_DEVICE_PROP, * PT_PNIO_DEVICE_PROP;
```

Comment: You need to show some code...

Comment: Hope my edit helps to get my problem: I do not understand why the PNIO_DEVICE_PROP structure has different values in a C++/CLI project. Why is the layout of the struct changing? It is the same native C++ structure in both cases, or am I missing something?

Comment: Pretty unclear how this happened, having to guess at these T_PNIO types does not help.  Be sure to wrap the #include for the .h file that contains this structure declaration with #pragma managed(push, off) and #pragma managed(pop) so the C++/CLI compiler assumes everything is native code.  And make sure that sizeof(T_PNIO_DEVICE_PROP) is the same everywhere.

Comment: Hello Hans,
Thank you for your quick reply and the great suggestions. I added the #pragmas, but it does not change anything. I determined the size in both cases, and there is the problem. The T_PNIO_DEVICE_PROP structure in my managed class is 260 bytes, in my unmanaged 258 bytes. How can this be?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was the problem with packing rules, which is also discussed in this post:
[C++ Struct Size unequal C++ Struct Size in C++/CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493390/c-struct-size-unequal-c-struct-size-in-c-cli)

I changed the structure in the included header file this way:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct PNIO_ATTR_PACKED
{
  /** MAC propertie */
  T_PNIO_MC_PROP      tMacProp;
  /** IP propertie */
  T_PNIO_IP_PROP      tIpParam;
  /** Name of station */
  T_PNIO_NAME_OF_STATION_PROP tNameOfStation;

}T_PNIO_DEVICE_PROP, * PT_PNIO_DEVICE_PROP;
#pragma pack
```

Thank you for your great advise.